# How to know sybase server started in multiplex Or single node mode?

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

Can someone help me with any command/stored proc to know in a running sybase database server 12.5 whether it was started in a single-node Or multiplex node.
I dont have access the startup log(s) ,any option around there to know this?
Currently I am using sybase 12.5.4 and planning to migrate it to 15.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it's not clear from your description, it sounds like you are running Sybase ASE 12.5.4.

Single and Multiplex nodes are a description for SAP Sybase IQ servers, not for SAP Sybase ASE servers.

Comment: The -iqmpx_sn 1 server startup option starts the server in single-node mode else its multiplex.[Found it here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc10082.1270/html/iqrblin/iqrblin289.htm)  So once the sybase IQ server is up , how to know in which mode it was started.

Comment: Well, we could have helped you sooner had you let us know the Software you were running.  Glad you found the answer.